# How can I extract the columns from a text file and save that into another text file?

Tags: text-processing

Suppose, I have a file called `source.txt` which has the following data in it:

```
3LWXA       199  XRAY        1.100    0.12    0.14
3LX3A       180  XRAY        1.550    0.15    0.17
3LY0A       364  XRAY        1.399    0.17    0.19
3LYDA       161  XRAY        1.450    0.17    0.19
3LYEA       307  XRAY        1.300    0.13    0.17
3LYHB       126  XRAY        1.600    0.17    0.21
3LYPA       215  XRAY        1.600    0.18    0.21
3M07A       618  XRAY        1.400    0.15    0.17
3M0FA       213  XRAY        1.600    0.21    0.22
```

I want to extract {1st} and {1st, 2nd} columns from `source.txt` and save them into `one.txt` and `two.txt`.

How can I do that?

---

**N.B.** I found [this thread](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/95024-need-get-first-column-text-file.html) but that didn't help.

Comment: what is the field separator? Tab(s)/Space(s)? main thing that it didn't work is because you didnt' provide the command with correct field delimiter .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk`.

```
awk '{ print $1 }' source.txt > one.txt
awk '{ print $1,  $2 }' source.txt > two.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Try also

```
awk '{print $1 > "one.txt"; print $1,$2 > "two.txt"}' source.txt
```

Comment: Good for two reasons: (1) Efficiency, only reads the input once, and therefore also (2) Works in a pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed` utilizing it's extended regex features enabled (-E), we can use the following:

```bsh
sed -En 's/\S+/&\n/2
  s/\n.*//wfile2
  s/\s.*//wfile1
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also do with cut command:

```
cat source.txt | sed 's/[ ]\+/:/g' | cut -d ":" -f 1 > one.txt
cat source.txt | sed 's/[ ]\+/:/g' | cut -d ":" -f 1-2 | tr ":" " " > two.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
res=re.compile(r'\s+')
fil=open('source.txt','r')
firs=open('one.txt','w')
sec=open('two.txt','w')
for f in fil:
    splitcomp=re.sub(res," ",f).strip().split(' ')
    firs.write(splitcomp[0].strip() + "\n")
    seondfilecon="{0}\t{1}".format(splitcomp[0],splitcomp[1])
    sec.write(seondfilecon.strip()+"\n")
```